# Linux create limited user

Tags: linux, security, python

I am working on a program to monitor multiple computers. The program resides on a raspberry pi and uses python to issue a reboot command over ssh to the various other Linux machines.

Thinking security wise, is there a way to create user 'foo' and only allow user 'foo' ssh login and the ability to 'sudo coldreboot'?

Answer (score 0):

A question from stackoverflow might be useful to you here:

> You can also restrict keys to permissible commands (in the authorized_keys file).
>
> I.e. the user would not log in via ssh and then have a restricted set of commands but rather would only be allowed to execute those commands via ssh (e.g. "ssh somehost bin/showlogfile")

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login)

You can also create users under a restricted shell and limit them to commands defined by `rssh.conf`:

Place user foo under a restricted shell:

`usermod -s /usr/bin/rssh foo`

Configure permissions under:

`nano /etc/rssh.conf`

- allowscp : Tells the shell that scp is allowed.
- allowsftp : Tells the shell that sftp is allowed.
- allowcvs : Tells the shell that cvs is allowed.
- allowrdist : Tells the shell that rdist is allowed.
- allowrsync : Tells the shell that rsync is allowed.

This should give you a good place to start.

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-restrict-shell-access-with-rssh.html)